# Why are pods still running after microk8s has been stopped?

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I'm in learning mode here, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question...

I have just installed microk8s on ubuntu following the instructions at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-a-local-kubernetes-with-microk8s

Everything works. The "microbot" application gets deployed and exposed and creates a simple web server.  But what surprised me is that after I stop microk8s (with "microk8s stop"), the web server is still apparently up and running.  It continues to respond to curl with its simple page content.

Is this expected behavior?  Do the pods continue to run after the orchestrator has stopped?

Also, I was trying to figure out what microk8s is doing with the network.  It fires up its dashboard on 10.152.183.203, but when I look at the interfaces and routing tables on my host, I can't figure out how traffic is being routed to that destination.  And if I run tcpdump I can't seem to capture any of the traffic being sent to that address.

Any explanation of what's going on here would be much appreciated!

- Duncan

Comment: I've voted to close this because it is two questions that should be separate questions on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what surprised me is that after I stop microk8s (with "microk8s stop"), the web server is still apparently up and running. It continues to respond to curl with its simple page content.
>
> Is this expected behavior? Do the pods continue to run after the orchestrator has stopped?

That's not expected behavior, and I can't reproduce it. What I see is that the service is available for a period of several seconds after running `microk8s stop`, but eventually everything gets shut down.

> Also, I was trying to figure out what microk8s is doing with the network. It fires up its dashboard on 10.152.183.203, but when I look at the interfaces and routing tables on my host, I can't figure out how traffic is being routed to that destination.

I've deployed Microk8s locally, and the dashboard Service looks like this:

```
root@ubuntu:~# kubectl -n kube-system get service kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.152.183.151   <none>        443/TCP   14m
```

As you note in your question, I can access this at `http://10.152.183.151`, but there are no local interfaces on that network:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ip addr |grep 10.152
<no results>
```

And there are no meaningful routes to that network. E.g., this shows that access to that ip would be via the default gateway, which doesn't make any sense:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ip route get 10.152.183.151
10.152.183.151 via 192.168.122.1 dev enp1s0 src 192.168.122.72 uid 0
    cache
```

What's going on? It turns out that microk8s sets up a bunch of NAT rules in your local firewall configuration. If we look for the dashboard address in the NAT table, we find:

```
root@ubuntu:~# iptables-legacy -t nat -S | grep 10.152.183.151
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.152.183.151/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-SVC-4HQ2X6RJ753IMQ2F
-A KUBE-SVC-4HQ2X6RJ753IMQ2F ! -s 10.1.0.0/16 -d 10.152.183.151/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
```

If we follow the chain, we find that:

1. Packets going to `10.152.183.151` enter the NAT `PREROUTING` chain, which sends them to the `KUBE-SERVICES` chain.
2. In the `KUBE-SERVICES` chain, packets to the dashboard (for tcp port 443) are sent to the `KUBE-SVC-4HQ2X6RJ753IMQ2F` chain.
3. In the `KUBE-SVC-4HQ2X6RJ753IMQ2F`, packets are first sent to the `KUBE-MARK-MASQ` chain, which sets a mark on the packet (which is used elsewhere in the configuration), and then gets sent to the `KUBE-SEP-SZAWMA3BPGJYVHOD` chain:

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~# iptables-legacy -t nat -S KUBE-SVC-4HQ2X6RJ753IMQ2F
   -A KUBE-SVC-4HQ2X6RJ753IMQ2F ! -s 10.1.0.0/16 -d 10.152.183.151/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
   -A KUBE-SVC-4HQ2X6RJ753IMQ2F -m comment --comment "kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard -> 10.1.243.198:8443" -j KUBE-SEP-SZAWMA3BPGJYVHOD
   ```
4. In the `KUBE-SEP-SZAWMA3BPGJYVHOD` chain, the packets finally hit a `DNAT` rule that maps the connection to the IP of the pod:

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~# iptables-legacy -t nat -S KUBE-SEP-SZAWMA3BPGJYVHOD
   -N KUBE-SEP-SZAWMA3BPGJYVHOD
   -A KUBE-SEP-SZAWMA3BPGJYVHOD -s 10.1.243.198/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
   -A KUBE-SEP-SZAWMA3BPGJYVHOD -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.243.198:8443
   ```

   We know that `10.1.243.198` is the Pod IP because we can see it like this:

   ```
   kubectl -n kube-system get pod kubernetes-dashboard-74b66d7f9c-plj8f -o jsonpath='{.status.podIP}'
   ```

So, we can reach the dashboard at `10.152.183.151` because the `PREROUTING` chain ultimately hits a `DNAT` rule that maps the "clusterip" of the service to the pod ip.

> And if I run tcpdump I can't seem to capture any of the traffic being sent to that address.

Based on the above discussion, if we use the pod ip instead, we'll see the traffic we expect. The following shows the result of me running `curl -k https://10.152.183.151` in another window:

```
root@ubuntu:~# tcpdump -n -i any -c10 host 10.1.243.198
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
19:20:33.441481 cali7ef1137a66d Out IP 192.168.122.72.33034 > 10.1.243.198.8443: Flags [S], seq 228813760, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3747829344 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:20:33.441494 cali7ef1137a66d In  IP 10.1.243.198.8443 > 192.168.122.72.33034: Flags [S.], seq 3905988324, ack 228813761, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1344719721 ecr 3747829344,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:20:33.441506 cali7ef1137a66d Out IP 192.168.122.72.33034 > 10.1.243.198.8443: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 3747829344 ecr 1344719721], length 0
19:20:33.442754 cali7ef1137a66d Out IP 192.168.122.72.33034 > 10.1.243.198.8443: Flags [P.], seq 1:518, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 3747829345 ecr 1344719721], length 517
19:20:33.442763 cali7ef1137a66d In  IP 10.1.243.198.8443 > 192.168.122.72.33034: Flags [.], ack 518, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 1344719722 ecr 3747829345], length 0
19:20:33.443004 cali7ef1137a66d In  IP 10.1.243.198.8443 > 192.168.122.72.33034: Flags [P.], seq 1:772, ack 518, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 1344719722 ecr 3747829345], length 771
19:20:33.443017 cali7ef1137a66d Out IP 192.168.122.72.33034 > 10.1.243.198.8443: Flags [.], ack 772, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3747829345 ecr 1344719722], length 0
19:20:33.443677 cali7ef1137a66d Out IP 192.168.122.72.33034 > 10.1.243.198.8443: Flags [P.], seq 518:582, ack 772, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3747829346 ecr 1344719722], length 64
19:20:33.443680 cali7ef1137a66d In  IP 10.1.243.198.8443 > 192.168.122.72.33034: Flags [.], ack 582, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 1344719723 ecr 3747829346], length 0
19:20:33.443749 cali7ef1137a66d In  IP 10.1.243.198.8443 > 192.168.122.72.33034: Flags [P.], seq 772:827, ack 582, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 1344719723 ecr 3747829346], length 55
10 packets captured
38 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: Sorry, I moved on and only now came back to look at this.  Thanks for the excellent answer, that's actually very informative.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that after stopping microk8s the pod's associated processes are still running.

I'm assuming they are never stopped by issuing the "microk8s stop" command.

Not sure if that was supposed to be the expected behavior, but normally I assumed that all the pod associated processes should be killed, too..

But, after starting microk8s, new processes are created for the pods.

I'm using MicroK8s v1.26.8 revision 5884.

```
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ PROMPT_COMMAND="date"
Tue 12 Sep 2023 11:57:52 AM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ microk8s status
microk8s is running
high-availability: no
  datastore master nodes: 127.0.0.1:19001
  datastore standby nodes: none
addons:
  enabled:
    dashboard            # (core) The Kubernetes dashboard
    dns                  # (core) CoreDNS
    ha-cluster           # (core) Configure high availability on the current node
    helm                 # (core) Helm - the package manager for Kubernetes
    helm3                # (core) Helm 3 - the package manager for Kubernetes
    hostpath-storage     # (core) Storage class; allocates storage from host directory
    ingress              # (core) Ingress controller for external access
    metrics-server       # (core) K8s Metrics Server for API access to service metrics
    registry             # (core) Private image registry exposed on localhost:32000
    storage              # (core) Alias to hostpath-storage add-on, deprecated
  disabled:
    cert-manager         # (core) Cloud native certificate management
    community            # (core) The community addons repository
    gpu                  # (core) Automatic enablement of Nvidia CUDA
    host-access          # (core) Allow Pods connecting to Host services smoothly
    kube-ovn             # (core) An advanced network fabric for Kubernetes
    mayastor             # (core) OpenEBS MayaStor
    metallb              # (core) Loadbalancer for your Kubernetes cluster
    minio                # (core) MinIO object storage
    observability        # (core) A lightweight observability stack for logs, traces and metrics
    prometheus           # (core) Prometheus operator for monitoring and logging
    rbac                 # (core) Role-Based Access Control for authorisation
Tue 12 Sep 2023 11:58:17 AM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ microk8s kubectl get pods | grep mysql
mysql-5c5556886-zvbg6                        1/1     Running                  92 (34m ago)     118d
haproxy-mysql-admin                          1/1     Running                  124 (33m ago)    104d
Tue 12 Sep 2023 11:59:21 AM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ 
Tue 12 Sep 2023 11:59:22 AM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ 
Tue 12 Sep 2023 11:59:22 AM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ ps aux | grep mysql
systemd+   65010  0.0  2.3 1614608 240640 ?      Ssl  11:25   0:01 mysqld
nicolae   106187  0.0  0.0   9040   716 pts/0    S+   12:00   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:00:07 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ 
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:00:24 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ 
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:00:24 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ sudo nsenter -t 65010 -u hostname
mysql-5c5556886-zvbg6
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:00:37 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ 
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:00:59 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ 
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:00:59 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ microk8s stop
Stopped.
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:02:10 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ 
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:02:36 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ 
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:02:36 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ microk8s kubectl get pods
microk8s is not running, try microk8s start
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:02:49 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ 
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:03:10 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ 
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:03:11 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ ps aux | grep mysql
systemd+   65010  0.0  2.3 1614608 240640 ?      Ssl  11:25   0:01 mysqld
nicolae   110162  0.0  0.0   9040   720 pts/0    S+   12:03   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:03:18 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ 
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:03:19 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ ps aux | grep mysql
systemd+   65010  0.0  2.3 1614608 240640 ?      Ssl  11:25   0:02 mysqld
nicolae   117868  0.0  0.0   8908   720 pts/0    R+   12:07   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:07:22 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ ps aux | grep mysql
systemd+   65010  0.0  2.3 1614608 240640 ?      Ssl  11:25   0:02 mysqld
nicolae   117930  0.0  0.0   9040   704 pts/0    S+   12:07   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:07:24 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ 
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:07:24 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ 
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:08:08 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ ps aux | grep mysql
systemd+   65010  0.0  2.3 1614608 240640 ?      Ssl  11:25   0:02 mysqld
nicolae   119226  0.0  0.0   9040   712 pts/0    S+   12:08   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:08:09 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ 
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:08:47 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ microk8s start
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:09:16 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ ps aux | grep mysql
systemd+  124297  0.5  1.8 1147668 186324 ?      Ssl  12:09   0:00 mysqld
nicolae   128970  0.0  0.0   9040   720 pts/0    S+   12:09   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:09:53 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$ microk8s version
MicroK8s v1.26.8 revision 5884
Tue 12 Sep 2023 12:10:58 PM EDT
nicolae@nicolae-VirtualBox:~$
```